May 2024 photo competition, Standing out
I'll be running the photo contest this month (May '24).
The topic is "standing out", meaning photos with one item which dominates the photo, like a solo stands out in a piece of music.
Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) prior to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.
The contest will end at the end of May (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.

If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics. Also, you can join us in chat to help us decide which topic to choose.

Marrakesh street scene
At first sight it is the imposing arch which stands out from the detail in this street scene.
But what takes over the picture is the character in the foreground, who has unexpectedly appeared in the shot and turned to look at the camera. Conspicuously dressed: wearing an elaborate hat, a garland, and an ornate shoulder bag, I suppose they would stand out anywhere.
I had to blur some faces but I estimate the subject to be a 30-40 year old male.

Photo taken by me in January 2011.

Note for counting thumbs-up, someone ignored the no downvotes rule. This photo does meet the rules of this months competition.

Not my downvote, but "strangely dressed" and "peculiar hat" usually carry a negative connotation in English, so some may read this as you publicly criticizing some innocent stranger's clothes. If that's not what you intend, maybe better words might be "unusual", "distinctive", "remarkable", etc

@user56reinstatemonica8 I had thought from previous months that the rule "you posted it, stand by it" applies to editing too, but is not mentioned this time. Edited the text, but not the picture.

Editing the text is acceptable, as is resizing the picture or adding a second version.

You get the virtual prize, two reasons to send in this photo, completely different and each of them acceptable. I agree that the person in the foreground is the more standing out one.

Well that's a surprise! Thanks.


Photo taken 14 April 2024, just outside Zaanse Schans, Zaandam, the Netherlands.
The name on the building says Roosmolen, which translates to Rose Mill.

That thing seems immense.

This was the highest voted post at the end of the month. Thanks.

I'm sure every traveller sees the beauty in small unknown flowers when in a foreign country, but how about this steel and aluminum Floralis Generica that is 23 m (75 ft) high?
Photo taken by me in Buenos Aires, Argentina, in February 2013.


Sadly, it's not doing so well these days (well, as of Jan 2024): https://imgur.com/a/VLNOuaO

@ex-user3761894 sad to see this...

Ok, with monuments it's easier, but this golden Buddha statue at Fo Guang Shan Main Shrine (Kaohsiung, Taiwan) can be noticed even miles away.
Indeed I like the proportion with the people (my cousin also taking a picture ahead of me and two passers by).
I took this photo in November 2023 with my Samsung A50 phone bought in 2020.



There is one grapefruit in this photo that nicely stands out!
Photo taken last month in an German grocery store near Frankfurt.

That does not look like a solist to me, more like the one who did not tune their instrument. It is within the competition rules.

I took this picture in Corfu Airport, Greece on the 4th of August 2023 (20:41).

Device: Redmi Note 8 Pro


This was taken in Magic Kingdom's Festival of Fantasy Parade.
I couldn't believe in my perfect timing to capture the exact moment of fire breathing.
Orlando, FL, USA. June 2015


On my way from North Shields, where the ferry from IJmuiden lands, the one often called Amsterdam to Newcastle, to Hartlepool, where I went to a meeting I had several stops in South Shields.
The last one at Marsden grotto which is really on the southern edge.
Just in front of the grotto there is Marsden Rock left in the sea from a now collapsed arch.
The water was coming up, earlier on you could see small grottos in the bottom part of the rock, by the time I took my picture they were mostly in the water.
Photo taken 8 May 2024, South Shields, Tyne and Wear, UK.

Taken (by me) a few weeks ago in Santiago (Chile). It's one of the resident cats of the hotel I was staying at.



Literally standing out :P
The place is Ponmudi hills, Western Ghats, Kerala, India and the human is my friend. Our college, IISER Trivandrum is just an hour away. The Bus ride to the hilltop along the hairpins covered with mist was one of the most beautiful ones we ever had.
Shot on my Pocophone F1 on 9th April 2023.
